# UTF-8 encoding problems between Android, JSon and PHP

Tags: java, php, android, json, utf-8

I programmed an Android App, which manages data to be stored and deleted in a MySQL database (on server). Whenever on the smartphone special characters ("ä", "ü", ...) are used the symbol is converted badly.

In the log I can see that the "Umlaut" (e.g. "ä") is transmitted properly. I also use in my php file "SET NAMES 'UTF-8'", see here:

```
function connect() 
{
    ....

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    // Selecting database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    return $con;
}
```

If I start a request via Postman, I can add words with special characters, e.g. "TÄST", the json response looks as follows:

```
{"catId":"35","category":"T\u00c4ST"}
```

So the words are well converted to UTF-8. But if I add an Item via smartphone, the response from the server (to retrieve the added item) looks like this:

```
{"catId":"37","category":"T?ST"}
```

The position in my code, where I add the parameters for the JSON Object is that (note that "name" is the string content of the edit text field):

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
...
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", catName));
```

After that the HTTPRequest is send:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_dest, "POST", params);
```

If I print out the params the word "Täst" is visible... But unfortunately I'm not able to check which json string is arriving on the server (due to my bad php knowledge). So where's the problem? In my android application or in the php files located on the server?

Do I have to encode the outgoing json object in any way?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To debug on Eclipse I suggest you:
http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt
It is quite easy to configure.

Control the encoding in the DB; maybe the VARCHAR default latin1_swedish_ci can't save that string.

Another way to solve it could be looking to the apache commons:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html
in particular the functions provided by: escapeHtml4 and unescapeHtml4

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! But unfortunately my php files are running on a remote server (bplaced.net), is it possible to debug there too? I don't have a clue of this.

Comment: Yes it is, but it is a little bit more complicated. You should install xdebug remotely and use Eclipse PDT.

I think this is a good guide:
http://bogdan-albei.blogspot.it/2010/06/php-remote-debugging-with-xdebug-and.html

Answer (score 0):

@dafocus, if you set your Android app project to UTF-8 encoding in your IDE, it should ensure that UTF-8 is handled properly in the app. It looks like an encoding change somewhere. You might not need to convert `TÄST` to `T\u00c4ST` at all if the encoding is UTF-8 throughout. PHP used to be difficult with charsets. I would suggest you to look at the PHP to figure out if the handler page causes this (possible) and/or the DB - as @madx just said.